# copy the dynamic code along with display it in dialog bos

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

currently i have multiple rows with different hidden book codes, when the person clicks on show code, it should show the popup dialog box with the code along with opening the concerned link in new window.

i have tried 2 methods but both not opening the link or revealing the code.the show code button does nothing

**APPROACH 1**

```
function show_code(num,url,bookcode) {
  document.getElementById('revealedcode-' + num).style.display = '';      
  document.getElementById('hiddencode-' + num).style.display = 'none'; 
  $( "#codebox" ).text(bookcode);
window.open(url);
$( "#codebox" ).dialog({
modal: true,width: "500px",Height: "250px",top:"50px",
position: ['center',0], 
});

};

var newWindow = window.open(url);
newWindow.blur();
window.focus();                   
return false;
```

}

html is

```
    <div class="right-pad clickbtn">
<a id="hiddencode-<?php echo $i; ?>"  href="#" onclick="show_code(<?php echo $i; ?>,'<?php echo $link ;?>','<?php echo $bookcode; ?>');">Show Code </a>

<a id="revealedcode-<?php echo $i; ?>"  style="display:none;" href="<?php echo $link ;?>"><?php echo $bookcode; ?></a>
</div>

       <div id="codebox"></div>
```

**APPROACH 2**

```
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 </style>


<script type="text/javascript">


function show_code(num,url,bookcode) {
      document.getElementById('revealedcode-' + num).style.display = '';      
      document.getElementById('hiddencode-' + num).style.display = 'none'; 

      // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('btn-' + num);

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn-' + num);


      $( "#couponbox" ).text(couponcode);

      // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

      // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
          }

    }
});     
       var newWindow = window.open(url);
    newWindow.blur();
    window.focus();                   
    return false;
}
</script>
```

html is for this is

```
 <div id="modal-<?php echo $i; ?>" class=" codeindex">


    <div>

            <h2><a href="#" onclick="show_code(<?php echo $i; ?>,'<?php echo $extlink ;?>','<?php echo $bookcode; ?>');"><?php echo the_title();?></a></h2> 

    </div>

    <div id="btn-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="right-pad clickbtn">
<a id="hiddencode-<?php echo $i; ?>"  href="#" onclick="show_code(<?php echo $i; ?>,'<?php echo $extlink ;?>','<?php echo $bookcode; ?>');">Show Code </a>

<a id="revealedcode-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;" href="<?php echo $extlink ;?>"><?php echo $bookcode; ?></a>
</div>

       <div id="codebox"></div> 

    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly is not working? Do you see any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `_BLANK` as part of the window properties for it's target. This will help ensure the browser will open a new blank window.

Consider the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="btn-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="right-pad clickbtn">
  <a id="hiddencode-<?php echo $i; ?>"  href="#" data-num="<?php echo $i; ?>" data-link="<?php echo $extlink ;?>" data-code="<?php echo $bookcode; ?>">Show Code </a>
  <a id="revealedcode-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;" href="<?php echo $extlink ;?>"><?php echo $bookcode; ?></a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function openWindow(url, trgt, opt) {
  if (opt == undefined) {
    opt = "location=yes,height=480,width=640,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
  }
  if (trgt == undefined) {
    trgt = "_BLANK";
  }
  return window.open(url, trgt, opt);
}

function show_code(num, url, bookcode) {
  $("#revealedcode-" + num).show();
  $("#hiddencode-" + num).hide();
  $("#codebox").html(bookcode);
  $("#codebox").dialog({
    open: function(e, ui) {
      var newWin = openWindow(url);
      newWin.blur();
      $(window).focus();
    },
    modal: true,
    width: "500px",
    Height: "250px",
    top: "50px",
    position: ['center', 0],
  });
};

$("a[id=^'hiddencode']").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var n = $(this).data("num"),
    l = $(this).data("link"),
    c = $(this).data("code");
  showCode(n, l, c);
});
```

This makes use of `data` attributes to help store extra data. We then bind a `click` event. I suspect they are not dynamically created, so you can use `.click()`. Just in case, I show it with `.on()`.

Comment: @angel I don't understand what you mean by "copy the code". To the clipboard? from one piece of HTML to another? I applied some updates. I'm unable to test any of the code presented as you have not provided a full example. Please clarify the issue.